# Debhelper recursive dependency

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Unfortunately, debhelper has a recursive dependency.

When I try to install with `apt-get source --compile debhelper`, it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
NOTICE: 'debootstrap' packaging is maintained in the 'Git' version control system at:
git://anonscm.debian.org/d-i/debootstrap.git
Skipping already downloaded file 'debootstrap_1.0.59ubuntu0.2.dsc'
Skipping already downloaded file 'debootstrap_1.0.59ubuntu0.2.tar.xz'
Need to get 0 B of source archives.
Skipping unpack of already unpacked source in debootstrap-1.0.59ubuntu0.2
dpkg-buildpackage: source package debootstrap
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.0.59ubuntu0.2
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution trusty
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Adam Conrad <adconrad@ubuntu.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build debootstrap-1.0.59ubuntu0.2
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: debhelper (>= 9)
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
Build command 'cd debootstrap-1.0.59ubuntu0.2 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
E: Child process failed
```

Then when I do `apt-get source --compile po4a`, it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
NOTICE: 'po4a' packaging is maintained in the 'Svn' version control system at:
svn://svn.debian.org/svn/po4a/trunk
Skipping already downloaded file 'po4a_0.45-1.dsc'
Skipping already downloaded file 'po4a_0.45.orig.tar.gz'
Skipping already downloaded file 'po4a_0.45-1.debian.tar.gz'
Need to get 0 B of source archives.
Skipping unpack of already unpacked source in po4a-0.45
dpkg-buildpackage: source package po4a
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 0.45-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Denis Barbier <barbier@debian.org>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build po4a-0.45
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: debhelper (>= 8) docbook-xml docbook-xsl xsltproc libterm-readkey-perl libunicode-linebreak-perl sp docbook libsgmls-perl texlive-binaries
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
Build command 'cd po4a-0.45 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
E: Child process failed
```

I can compile every other package but debhelper, because it requires po4a, which requires debhelper, and so on and so forth.

EDIT: BTW, I have **no *sudo*** access.

Comment: Yes, this is why bootstrapping new architectures is difficult. `gcc` build-depends on `gcc` for another example.

Comment: Some context would not hurt. What are you trying to do here? Why not use the binary packages for your arch?

Comment: I already said, I _don't_ have root access.

Answer (score 4):

`debhelper` can be built without NLS, which doesn't require `po4a`; see https://bugs.debian.org/709557 for details. Once you have the source for `debhelper`, you can run

```
USE_NLS=no dpkg-buildpackage -d -b -uc
```

to get an installable `.deb`, which you can then use to build `po4a` and then rebuild `debhelper` with NLS.

Note that `debhelper` is an `Architecture: all` package, so it doesn't need to be rebuilt for new architectures, so it isn't tracked in the [bootstrapping effort](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBootstrap).

Comment: BTW, I can't install any packages on my system;that's the whole point of compiling from source;I have no sudo access.

Comment: How are you handling dependencies for anything else if you can't install anything? Are you manually installing everything in your home directory?

Comment: that is how I am handling dependencies for everything else.

Comment: Could you give a detailed example of the commands you're running then? I'd like to see how you built one of the other packages you managed to build in this fashion.

Comment: all I'm running is `apt-get source --compile [package]`

Comment: How do you satisfy the build-dependencies?

Comment: I do `apt-get source --compile [deps]`.

Comment: I meant, how do you make the build-dependencies available so you can compile dependent packages? In your example above, `po4a` depends on `docbook-xml` amongst other packages; how do you make `docbook-xml` available to build `po4a` if you can't install anything?

Comment: I just compile the dependencies using `apt-get source --compile [dep-deps]`.